# Postgres Date Compare with ISO timestamp

Tags: postgresql

When I perform a > than query on a `timestampz` field it seems to include dates that are equal to the date I'm querying with.  At least when I'm comparing to an ISO date string?

```
   select
     created,
     to_char(created, 'MI:SS:MS')
   from
    private.event
   where
    created > '2020-03-24T05:14:08.082Z'
```

Results

```
created            |to_char  |
-------------------|---------|
2020-03-24 18:14:08|14:08:082|
2020-03-24 18:14:08|14:08:180|
```

I'm not expecting the first row in that result.

FYI if I adjust the query so that I compare with `'2020-03-24T05:14:08.083Z'` it goes away.

Does anyone know whats going on here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgres timestamps have [microsecond resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) even if they're displayed with millisecond resolution. So you're effectively searching for `>'2020-03-24T05:14:08.082000Z'` while that first result is probably non-zero in one or more of those last three hidden digits.